# Must I use sed's hold space for this?

Tags: sed

I wanted to source the system xinitrc except the last paragraph
in my local xinitrc, so I used

```
    % sed -n 'H
            /^exec ./{
                    x
                    s/\([^\n]\+\n\)\+exec.*//
                    p
            }' /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc
```

That is, when `^exec` is encountered, I print everything up to
that point except the exec line and the above part of its paragraph.

My question is: could this have been done more simply?  Could
it, for instance, have been done without using the hold space?
I tried using N, but couldn't make it work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

In `sed`, "and the above part of its paragraph" basically means yes. If you want to decide whether or not to print lines based on the content of later lines, you're pretty much gonna have to use the buffer, *unless* you can restructure your paradigm.

What defines the "paragraph"? Is it consistent? `perl` and `awk` will let you define fairly arbitrary record separators. You might try something like this:

```
$: awk 'BEGIN{ RS="if " }
        /exec/{ exit; }
        { print }
       ' /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc
```

I recommend studying your data for a better separator, though.